# Dynamic routes using Camel & Quarkus

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus

I am trying to use Apache Camel with Quarkus to achieve some kind of edge service functionalities, I am checking out Route Templates of Camel but it is not directing to correct service endpoints, my

application.properties config :

```
camel.main.route-template[0].template-id=rest  
camel.main.route-template[0].hello-url=http://localhost:8081/hello-resteasy 
camel.main.route-template[0].quark-url=http://localhost:8081/resteasy-jackson/quarks
```

and my route builder :

```
routeTemplate("rest")
                .templateParameter("hello-url")
                .templateParameter("quark-url")
        .from("platform-http:/hello2")
                .removeHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH)
                .choice()
                    .when(header("Authorization").contains("-"))
                        .setHeader("Accept", constant("application/json"))
                        .to("{{hello-url}}/quarks?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                    .otherwise()
                        .setHeader("Accept", constant("text/plain"))
                        .to("{{quark-url}}?bridgeEndpoint=true")
                        .to("log:DEBUG?showBody=true&showHeaders=true")
                .endChoice();
```

I am using Quarkus version : 1.12.2.Final
My extension list :
[camel-attachments, camel-core, camel-http, camel-jackson, camel-jsonpath, camel-log, camel-microprofile-health, camel-microprofile-metrics, camel-platform-http, camel-support-common, camel-support-commons-logging, camel-support-httpclient, camel-xml-io, cdi, mutiny, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-health, smallrye-metrics, vertx, vertx-web]

Appreciate your help or if you have better solution please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean with "it is not directing to correct service endpoint" ?

Comment: I mean it gives 404 error/Resource not found.

Comment: this may not depend on the camel route, can you please provide more informations about which service endpoint is wrongly invoked ?

Comment: How can I print where the request is being redirected ? pardon my question but I am new to Camel :)

Comment: you can increase the log level but the endpoint should be also in the header printed by the log endpoint